# Visual studio Intellisense color-coding not working for unity script editing

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am using visual studio to edit scripts of unity for game developing. At first it was working properly. But for some personal reasons I have to reinstall unity and visual studio ( Unity auto downloads visual studio when it is setuped. First time also done that same way). But, after that VS is not showing intelligence suggestion for unity function for example "Input" etc etc which it was showing before. It has also stopped working to show those function in color. They are just in plain black color now. Help me with solutions. I have attached a schreenshot.
[This is my VS showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jrRwj.png)
[This is what it was showing before(Collected from internet)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4BKGK.png)

Comment: What is your programming question?

Comment: I am just learning from their official tutorial ,which is showing how to make  ROLL A BALL game. @user1511417

Comment: What is your programming question?